# Inefficient MySQL database/statements slowing PHP/JS system down

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have developed a fairly ramshackle PHP/JavaScript Reward system for my school's VLE.

The main bulk of the work is done on a `transactions` table which has the following fields:

`Transaction_ID`, `Datetime`, `Giver_ID`, `Recipient_ID`, `Points`, `Category_ID`, `Reason`

The idea is that if I, as a member of staff, give a student some Reward Points, an entry such as this is inserted into the database:

```
INSERT INTO `transactions` (`Transaction_ID`, `Datetime`, `Giver_ID`, `Recipient_ID`, `Points`, `Category_ID`, `Reason`) VALUES
(60332, '2012-02-22', 34985, 137426, 5, 5, 'Excellent volcano homework.');
```

This worked fine - but I didn't really consider just how much the system would be used. I now have over **72,000 transactions** in this table.

As such, a few of my pages are starting to slow down. For instance, when staff try to allocate points, my system runs a command to get the member of staff's total point allocation and other snippets of information. This appears to be displaying rather slowly, and looking at the MySQL statement/accompanying PHP code, I think this could be much more efficient.

```
function getLimitsAndTotals($User_ID) {

    $return["SpentTotal"] = 0;
    $return["SpentWeekly"] = 0;

    $sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `transactions` 
        WHERE `Giver_ID` =$User_ID";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $return["SpentTotal"] += $row["Points"];

            $transaction_date = strtotime ($row["Datetime"]);

            if ($transaction_date > strtotime( "last sunday" )) {
                $return["SpentWeekly"] += $row["Points"];
            }
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

As such, my question is twofold.

1. Can this specific code be optimised?
2. Can I employ any database techniques - full text indexing or the like - to further optimise my system?

---

**EDIT**: RE Indexing

I don't know anything about indexing, but it looks like my `transactions` table does actually have an index in place?

[image: Transaction table index]

Is this the correct type of index?

Here is the code for table-creation:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
  `Transaction_ID` int(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Datetime` date NOT NULL,
  `Giver_ID` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `Recipient_ID` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `Points` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `Category_ID` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `Reason` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Transaction_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=74927 ;
```

---

Thanks in advance,

Comment: 72,000 records is a drop in the bucket to a database. That alone shouldn't be slowing you down.

Comment: Can you show us your table create statement? Perhaps you need to add a few indexes.

Comment: Thanks - added that information phpdev.

Comment: Have you profiled your scripts? Rather than trying to guess where the bottlenecks are you should profile the worst scripts to find where they are. Much more reliable and you should then be able to prove you've improved the performance for those scripts.

Comment: Hi liquorvicar. Thanks for the post, but I'm afraid I have no idea what profiling involves! Do you have a link I can study?

Comment: Let me ask you a question. Do you run this code as a single call or inside of the loop? Do you have any sql queries run inside of the loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `Giver_ID` is **indexed**. Try also running the strtotime outside of your while loop as I imagine its an expensive operation to be running 72,000 times.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {

    // assign the unix timestamp of last sunday here.
    $last_sunday = strtotime('last sunday');

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $return["SpentTotal"] += $row["Points"];

        $transaction_date = strtotime ($row["Datetime"]);

        if ($transaction_date > $last_sunday) {
            $return["SpentWeekly"] += $row["Points"];
        }
    }
}
```

Also consider running `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Datetime) AS datetime_timestamp` in your SQL instead of getting it out as a string and running another expensive strtotime operation. You can then simply run:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {

    // assign the unix timestamp of last sunday here.
    $last_sunday = strtotime('last sunday');

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $return["SpentTotal"] += $row["Points"];

        if ($row['datetime_timestamp'] > $last_sunday) {
            $return["SpentWeekly"] += $row["Points"];
        }
    }
}
```

(if your column is of type DATE, of course!)

Comment: Column is of type "DATETIME". Will your suggest code still operate as expected?

Comment: Excellent. I've given it a quick go and your suggested changes do appear to have vastly decreased the loading time. Thanks Tom :)

Comment: @dunc this simply can't be. these "advises" are complete rubbish. Either you had no actual performance problems before or you are still have them now. you had an index already and strtotime is NOT that slow operation to be noticed.

Comment: Can you say that with complete confidence YCS, considering you don't know the calibre of systems - especially hardware - in place? I'm not being facetious, but genuinely querying. I didn't run any scientific tests on the page but from trying the same page on a number of different logins prior to this code, then the same logins after, the loading speed of my middle pane (totals, etc.) has most certainly - visibly - improved.

Comment: @dunc Well, your feelings failed you. A programmer shouldn't operate such terms like "faster" or "slower", but certain numbers only. The only improvement you have got from this answer is moving strtotime out of the loop. Well, place `$start = microtime(1);` before it and `echo number_format(microtime(1)-$start);` after and run it with both this "improvement" and without it. And tell us the difference. A real difference, not some vague "visible" "feeling".

Comment: @YourCommonSense - this was advice that I made to someone that was looking for improvments on his code. I have suggested two ways that would perhaps speed it up (and he said it did!), even though I know nothing about the system. This is a community for advice and suggestions, as well as definitive answers. No need to get your back up about it!

Comment: I didn't accuse him of being a liar at any point, my vague answer while **hideously misguided** was polite.

Answer (score 0):

72k is nothing... However there could be other things here that are causing slowdowns, like your mysql configuration (how much memory you allocated to the service), and a few others (do a search for optimizing mysql).

Also look at how many `INSERTS` you have in a given page, that will typically slow down your page load, if you are doing an insert every action for a user, you are making a costly transaction.

Typically a SELECT is much less expensive than an INSERT, etc;

From your SQL code I can also assume you didn't optimize your queries, something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM `transactions` 
    WHERE `Giver_ID` =$User_ID";
```

Should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT Points, DateTime FROM ..."
```

(not a big issue from your data, but it only requests WHAT YOU NEED, not everything which would require more memory while going through the iteration).

Also not sure how your schema is designed, but are you using indexing on `Transaction_ID`?

Answer (score 0):

> Can this specific code be optimized?

Yes.
But definitively not by "looking at the code".

> Can I employ any database techniques - full text indexing or the like - to further optimise my system?

Nope, you can't.
Simply **because you have no idea,** what certainly is slow in your system.

This is merely a common sense, widely used in the real life by anyone, but for some reason it become completely forgotten when someone start to program a web-site.

Your question is like "my car is getting slow. How to speed it up?". WHO ON THE EARTH CAN ANSWER IT, knowing no reason of the slowness? Is it tyres? Or gasoline? Or there is no road around but an open field? Or just someone forgot to release a hand brake?

### You have to determine the slowness reason first.

**Before** asking a question you have to measure your query runtime.
And if it's still fast, you should not blame it for the slowness of your site.
And start **profiling** it.

First of all you have to determine what part of the whole page makes it load slow. It could be just some Javascript loading from the third-party server.
So, start with "Net" tab in the Firebug and see the most slow part.

then proceed to it.
If it's your PHP code - use `microtime(1);` to measure different parts to spot the problem one.

### Then come with the question.

However, if take your question not as a request for the speed optimization, but for the more sanity in SQL, there are some improvements that can be made.

Both numbers can be retrieved as a single values.

```
select sum(Points) as Total from FROM `transactions` WHERE Giver_ID=$User_ID
```

will give you tital points
as well as

```
$sunday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('last sunday'));

select sum(Points) as Spent from FROM `transactions` 
WHERE Giver_ID=$User_ID AND Datetime > '$sunday'
```

will give you weekly points.

Comment: Although I don't appreciate the somewhat patronising tone to your post, you raise a valid point, so +1. However, I'm not coming in to this completely blind - as I stated, I know which specific segment of the system is loading slower than the rest and as such narrowed it down to the associated code. I know it is "the brakes", and that the "brake discs" are just fine and by applying common sense I have whittled the problem down to being "some other part of the brake system", "most likely the brake pads". As such, others were able to offer answers which have indeed helped to resolve the problem..

Comment: ..but your clarification of profiling and offering suggestions on determining the problem exactly are useful, so thanks.

Comment: It's a lie. No other answer offered a real help.

Comment: However, some of the advises were not that useless. Many INSERTS indeed slows down a system. But as far as I can see, it's inapplicable in your case. And nevertheless, any advise should be given only based on the certain numbers.